# Error Alamofire 5 response success and response failure

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I was using Alamofire with version 4 and it was working very well. When I update Alamofire to version 5, it gives me an error getting the result response ".success" or ".failure"

[image]

How can I get the result response ".success" or ".failure" with Alamofire 5?

```
AF.upload(multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in

            multipartFormData.append(imgData!, withName: "signature", fileName: String("signature"), mimeType: "image/jpg")

            for (key, value) in parameters {
                multipartFormData.append((value.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!), withName: key)
            }
        },
        to: URL,
        method: .post,
        headers: headers) { (result) in
            switch result {
            case .success(let upload, _, _):

                upload.uploadProgress(closure: { (progress) in
                    print("Upload Progress: \(progress.fractionCompleted)")
                })

                upload.responseJSON { response in
                    print("Succes: ", response.result.value ?? "")
                    if let data = response.data {
                        do {
                            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                            let model = try decoder.decode(T.self, from: data)
                            success(model)
                        } catch let error as NSError {
                            print(error)
                        }
                    }
                }
            case .failure(let encodingError):
                print("error: ", encodingError)
            }
        }
```

Comment: Did you get the solution for the above issue?

Answer (score 0):

In Alamofire 5.0 why you need success and failure ? i am achieving it with code below

```
  static func uploadFile(url: String, fileData: Data?, parameters: [String : String], type: MessageType!, fileName: String!, completionHandler: @escaping (Result<Data, Error>) -> Void) {

        _ = AF.upload(multipartFormData: { (multiFormData) in
            var fileType: String!
            if type! == MessageType.Video {
                fileType = "video/mp4"
            } else if type! ==  MessageType.Image {
                fileType = "image/jpeg"
            }
            multiFormData.append(fileData!, withName: "uploadedfile", fileName: fileName , mimeType: fileType)
            for (key, value) in parameters {
                multiFormData.append(value.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!, withName: key)
            }
        }, to: url).uploadProgress(queue: .main, closure: { progress in
            print("Upload Progress: \(progress.fractionCompleted)")
        }).responseJSON(completionHandler: { response in
            if response.error != nil {
                completionHandler(.failure(response.error!))
            } else {
                completionHandler(.success(response.data!))
            }
        })



    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue few days ago, here is the working code for this.

> pod 'Alamofire', '5.1.0'

```
    AF.upload(multipartFormData: { (mulipartFormData) in
        for (key, value) in parameters {
            mulipartFormData.append(value.data(using: .utf8)!, withName: key)
        }
        for (image, key) in images {
            let imgData = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: compression)!
            mulipartFormData.append(imgData, withName: key, fileName: "\(key).jpeg", mimeType: "image/jpeg")
        }

    }, to: url, method: .post, headers:  HTTPHeaders(headers)).response { response in

        onComplete(response.data, response.response, response.error)

    }.uploadProgress { progress in

        print("progress: \(progress.fractionCompleted * 100)")
        onProgress?(progress)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To determine if request is successful, with AF 5 you can do this like that in the response block (response, responseData, responseJSON, ...):

```
switch response.result {
case .success:
    // get the data
case .failure:
    // error
}
```

OR just check:

```
response.value != nil
```